# Word/text wrap within each tile of a Google visualization Treemap

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How do I wrap the text within each rectangle or tile of a Google visualization Treemap so that the words are not truncated with an ellipsis but instead try to fill up the tile instead?

For example, the label for US get truncated below.

treemap.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['treemap']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
          [{v:'Global', f:'Gbl'},    null,                 0,                               0],
          [{v:'America', f:'AM'},   'Global',             0,                               0],
          [{v:'Europe', f:'EU'},    'Global',             0,                               0],
          [{v:'Asia', f:'AS'},      'Global',             0,                               0],
          [{v:'Australia', f:'AU'}, 'Global',             0,                               0],
          [{v:'Africa', f:'AF'},    'Global',             0,                               0],
          [{v:'Brazil', f:'BR'},    'America',            11,                              10],
          [{v:'USA', f:'USSSS SSSS SSSSS SSSSS SSSSSS SSSSS SSSSSS SSSS SSSS SSSSS SSSSS SSSS SSSS SSSS SSSSS SSSSSS SSSSSS SSSSSS SSS SSSS SSSSS SSS SSSS SSS SSSS'},       'America',            52,                              31],
          [{v:'Mexico', f:'MX'},    'America',            24,                              12],
          [{v:'Canada', f:'CA'},    'America',            16,                              -23],
          [{v:'France', f:'FR'},    'Europe',             42,                              -11],
          [{v:'Germany', f:'DE'},   'Europe',             31,                              -2],
          [{v:'Sweden', f:'SE'},    'Europe',             22,                              -13],
          [{v:'Italy', f:'IT'},     'Europe',             17,                              4],
          [{v:'UK', f:'UK'},        'Europe',             21,                              -5],
          [{v:'China', f:'CH'},     'Asia',               36,                              4],
          [{v:'Japan', f:'JP'},     'Asia',               20,                              -12],
          [{v:'India', f:'IN'},     'Asia',               40,                              63],
          [{v:'Laos', f:'LA'},      'Asia',               4,                               34],
          [{v:'Mongolia', f:'MO'},  'Asia',               1,                               -5],
          [{v:'Israel', f:'IS'},    'Asia',               12,                              24],
          [{v:'Iran', f:'IR'},      'Asia',               18,                              13],
          [{v:'Pakistan', f:'PA'},  'Asia',               11,                              -52],
          [{v:'Egypt', f:'EG'},     'Africa',             21,                              0],
          [{v:'S. Africa', f:'SA'}, 'Africa',             30,                              43],
          [{v:'Sudan', f:'SU'},     'Africa',             12,                              2],
          [{v:'Congo', f:'CO'},     'Africa',             10,                              12],
          [{v:'Zaire', f:'ZA'},     'Africa',             8,                               10]
        ]);

        var options = {
          minColor: '#f00',
          midColor: '#ddd',
          maxColor: '#0d0',
          maxDepth: 4,          
          headerHeight: 15,
          showTooltips: true,
          fontColor: 'black'
        };

        var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
        var tree = new google.visualization.TreeMap(chart_div);

        tree.draw(data, options);   
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 1600px; height: 900px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if this is possible with Google visualization Treemap. I have seen FR in the github site but it has been outstanding for a couple of years.

If this is not possible with Google visualization, are there any other javascript package to create nested treemaps with word wrap for names within nodes like [this](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.0/doc/html/tree/tree_what_is_a_treemap.htm)?

Comment: @WhiteHat apologies. Have edited the example to be more realistic.

Comment: so the problem here, the chart offers no wrap but smaller font -- you could find `...` and replace once the `'ready'` event fires, but there's not much to relate the chart element back to the data table in order to get the correct value -- especially when the entire cell contents are `...`, as with one of the small squares on the bottom of the example provided...

Comment: Treemaps created in Google Sheets wrap tile labels, so it should be possible. I am not able to find a way to do it in the api

Comment: Had to write my own word wrap and ellipsis